# Почему предыдущие ос не удалились при установке новой ос?

Tags: uefi

[image: Как их удалить?]

Я вроде нажимал форматировать диск и установить новую ос... Почему так происходит? А как теперь их удалить?

Comment: Если ты удалил разделы жёсткого диска, то это не говорит о том что ты удалил разделы с загрузчиками.

Comment: Даже удаление разделов с загрузчиками совсем не обязательно избавит от загрузочных записей, которые записаны прямо в настройки uefi

Comment: Проверял, что не удалились? Загрузить пробовал?